# How to capitalize english string in Emacs

Tags: string, emacs, elisp

I'm wondering what's people using to correctly capitalize english strings since ''capitalize'' won't do the job:

```
(capitalize "can't")
=> "Can'T"
```

Although writing this function is trivial, I'm wondering if there's a preferred built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe if you temporarily add `'` to the current word constituent syntax table:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?' "w")

(capitalize "can't")
=> "Can't"
```

Comment: +1, one caution with this however: 
(capitalize "this is a 'test'") 
"This Is A 'test'"

Answer (score 5):

I have M-c bound to capitalize-word, and it works to capitalize `can't` correctly.

Comment: capitalize-word works because it sees "can't" as two words, can and t. This is why originally said strings instead of words. With capitalize-word I'd have to loop over all the words in the string and it'd end up capitilizng the "t"s.

Comment: Nope, that's not right.  capitalize-word sees can't as a single word.  It does not capitalize the t.  But it is an interactive function that capitalizes the following word (or N awords) in the current buffer.  It is not a function that applies to the passed string.  So it wouldn't work for you, anyway.

Comment: I thought the same thing  but if you run `M-2 M-x capitalize-word` on "can't" you'll get "Can'T".  So, it does see "can't" as two words.

Comment: just did this twice.  In a text file, it works as I described, treating can't as a single word. When the word "can't" appears in a comment inside a C-Sharp file, it works as *you* described, treating can't as 2 words.

Answer (score 1):

Current answers are fine, but if you work with strings in code, you can use [`s`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) string manipulation library. [`s-capitalize`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-capitalize-s) capitalizes the first word in a sentence.

```
ELISP> (s-capitalize "can't win the war on drugs in a prison, where the hell you gonna win it?")
"Can't win the war on drugs in a prison, where the hell you gonna win it?"
ELISP> (s-join " " (-map 's-capitalize (s-split " " "can't win the war on drugs in a prison, where the hell you gonna win it?")))
"Can't Win The War On Drugs In A Prison, Where The Hell You Gonna Win It?"
```

[`s-titleize`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-titleize-s) capitalizes every word in a string, but it's a simple wrapper around built-in `capitalize`, therefore [Karl Voigtland's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314734/596361) applies.

```
ELISP> (s-titleize "Girl, you can't even think of calling this shit a war.")
"Girl, You Can'T Even Think Of Calling This Shit A War."
ELISP> (progn (modify-syntax-entry ?' "w") (s-titleize "Girl, you can't even think of calling this shit a war."))
"Girl, You Can't Even Think Of Calling This Shit A War."
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior depends of course on the syntax-table in use, i.e. depends on the major-mode.  If the `'` character has the `"w p"` syntax, then it should work correctly.  This is the case in text-mode, but not in most programming modes.